# Can't connect to WiFi with ubuntu 12.10 on DELL Studio 15

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, dell

At first I installed 32bit ubuntu 12.10 & struggled much setting the WiFi by help of so many answer here then I thought to install 64bit as my system is of 64bit. At the installation time itself I couldn't find any WiFi name listed & I connect through wire. Though I have 3 WiFi running here...
I am not able to see the ENABLE WIRELESS in checking condition or I cant find any driver for WiFi in additional drivers tab in software sources.

What can be the problem ? Is this laptop doesn't work for WiFi with ubuntu ?

I don't have exp with ubuntu for any troubleshooting though I use for around 1 year..

Edited content--

Result of

> lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port [8086:0045] (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:3b48] (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:3b4a] (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:3b4c] (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b09] (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b29] (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 06)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series] [1002:68e0]
02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series] [1002:aa68]
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
07:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller [1180:e822] (rev 01)
07:00.1 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5U2xx (R5U230 / R5U231 / R5U241) [Memory Stick Host Controller] [1180:e230] (rev 01)
07:00.2 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe xD-Picture Card Controller [1180:e852] (rev 01)
07:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:e832] (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 05)
```

Result of

> sudo lshw -c network

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:24:d6:43:c0:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-17-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:45 memory:f0500000-f0501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: b8:ac:6f:68:08:6d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff memory:f0420000-f043ffff
```

Result of

> rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include result of `lspci -nn` , `sudo lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all`

Comment: @Web-E : I have edited but it's line by line...editor is simply taking everything together...

Comment: it showing, the device is detected and ready. But is hard blocked. Means the hardware switch that controls wi-fi is turned off. Please turn it on. If it is a Fn+F<1-12> key, please test whether those keys are working under linux.

Comment: F buttons are working as I see many things happening but at the press of F2, where wireless is marked...nothing is happening

Comment: you tried Fn+F2 or F2 only ?

Comment: @Web-E - I tried simple F2 & it's enables....thanks for the patience with a novice like me...

Comment: @Web-E Put this as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showing, the device is detected and ready. But is hard blocked. Means the hardware switch that controls wi-fi is turned off. Please turn it on. If it is a Fn+F<1-12> key, please test whether those keys are working under linux.

Also try without Fn key (use just F2, if its F2 for wi-fi).